# gnuplot 5.0 rc1 default terminal type on Windows

Tags: terminal, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel rc1 on Windows 7. I noticed that its default terminal (or theme, not sure what it is called) looks like this:

http://neo.graceland.edu/~zhu/images/10x10x10.png

So when I save my scripts to a .plt file and double click it to plot, the same result pops up except that it is not interactive, i.e., I can't drag to rotate the plot!

I thought it may be caused by improper terminal type, so I added 'set term wxt' to my script, and what it looks like this:

http://neo.graceland.edu/~zhu/images/10x10x10_wxt.png

Notice that icons on top of the plot have changed. This seems solved the problem of non-interaction, but the drag and rotate feature of 'wxt' isn't as smooth as the default term - I can feel the lag when I drag it. Any idea? Here is my script (after adding 'set term wxt'):

```
set xrange [-1:11]
set yrange [-1:11]
set zrange [-1:11]
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set zlabel "z"
set view equal xyz
set ticslevel 0
set term wxt

do for [ii=0:19] {
    splot 'cubic10_newdata.txt' every :::ii::ii using 1:2:3:($4/3):($5/3):($6/3) with vectors
}
```

Comment: Correct, you shouldn't open it with a double-click, but rather start `wgnuplot.exe` and then do `load 'myfile.plt'`. BTW: In the plot you'll only see the result of your last iteration with `ii=19` which overrides the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks. The purpose of the for loop is to make an animation of how data change over time, and as you pointed out, in the end only the last frame will be shown.